# How do I pass test data to a regression equation in python?

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, prediction, regression-testing

I have built a regression equation for a train dataframe (b) which has all the Xs (input variables) in collist. My response variable - Y is SalePrice.

```
X = b[collist].values
y = b[['SalePrice']]
reg2 = LinearRegression()
reg2.fit(X, y)
(reg2.intercept_, reg2.coef_)
```

I got an array of coefficients.

```
(array([-1003980.93890187]),
 array([[  1.13921901e+01,   6.72094755e-01,   3.57706059e+02,
           9.11889135e+01,   1.74211742e+01,   1.49978955e+01,
           1.01590205e+01,  -2.39999419e+00,   2.27570861e+01,
           ..........
           ..more terms...
           1.88596429e+01,   3.57099213e+01,  -2.91352714e+01,
           2.54343753e+01,   1.79479162e+03,   6.95632849e+02,
           3.97891154e+03,   1.67768978e+03,  -2.06711712e+03,
          -4.70429021e+03]]))
```

How do I identify which coefficient is for which term?

Also, how do I pass a test dataframe in this equation and get response variable?

for test data, I got another dataframe as well in which, column for SalePrice(response) is absent.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to `zip` the column names with the coefficients...

```
[name, coef for name, coef in zip(b.columns, reg2._coef)
```

As far as predicting on the test frame it should be something like

`reg2.predict(test_df)`

You can also call score for out of sample R squared

```
reg2.score(test_X, test_y)
```

Just look up the [documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html).